# Where do I create folder "upload" in my server on google cloud to store files uploaded?

Tags: node.js, image, file, gcloud

I am working on a Nodejs app, I have created a folder named "upload" on my app's directory public folder, this folder stores files that are uploaded using Nodejs. This works well when its locally now on Google Cloud where do I create that "upload" folder to be able to store my uploaded images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a documentation [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/) to use node.js with cloud storage, that may help you.
You can found more details about cloud storage [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "folder" on GCP using Buckets (Storage). First, you'll need to [create one](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets). You can either make the whole bucket publicly readable or private (or do the same to every object, you'll see this option on the bucket)

Once you are done with creation, head into the docs for [Uploading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs). You can also see all other techniques on the second link if you need to. Just click on the "Code Samples" and pick NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you, I finally won